# Curve fitting a closed loop polynomial to circular data

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, least-squares

**Hello!** I'm in the process of making a very basic racetrack simulator, for this I am currently fitting a piecewise polynomial to a set of points representing the "raceline" of the track, this then allows me to calculate the minimum radius of curvature of the track and thus the minimum speed I can take around a corner. It is working fine so far like this - but I've hit a snag. My radius of curvature varies significantly depending on how fine I interpolate my track. Ideally, I want something as true to real life (and with continuous curvature) as possible, and so I was hoping that if I could fit a degree $n$ bounded (circular) polynomial to my data, I'd be able to get a more accurate estimate of the minimum radius of curvature, and it would also simplify my calculations significantly, as it is easily differentiable. How would I go about fitting this type of polynomial to a set of $(x, y)$ coordinate data? I feel out of my depth.

$$ f(x, y) = \sum_{n=0}^{n} a_{(2n)2}y^{2n} + a_{(2n)1}x^{2n} + a_{(2n-1)2}y^{2n-1} + a_{(2n-1)2}y^{2n-1}$$

Am I needlessly over-complicating things? I feel like this would be something I would calculate once per track, and thus smooth out any errors in my track data.

Track processing image:

[image]

Comment: I am not so sure of your problem, but usually one would use bezier curves  to smooth any path.

Comment: If you use polynomial splines, to get continuous curvature, you need a continuous second derivative. Thus at each end of a curve segment, you would need to match the value, the derivative, and the second derivative with the next curve segment. This is six degrees of freedom, so you need 6 parameters to meet it. That is, you would need a quintic (degree 5) spline.